# How to update only one partition field when the hive table has multiple partition fields?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table called `table`, it has two string partition field, `years`and`month`. Now I only want to update the `years` partition but not update `month` partition.

I tried the sql below but failed.

```
ALTER TABLE table PARTITION (years='2021') RENAME TO PARTITION (years='2020');
```

Apache calcite logged that

> org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: Sql 1: From line 1, column 43 to line 1, column 84: Number of target table partition columns 2 does not equal number of source partition columns 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since partition is a folder structure, you need to mention all partition names.

```
ALTER TABLE table PARTITION (years='2021',month='1') RENAME TO PARTITION (years='2020',month='1');
ALTER TABLE table PARTITION (years='2021',month='2') RENAME TO PARTITION (years='2020',month='2');
ALTER TABLE table PARTITION (years='2021',month='3') RENAME TO PARTITION (years='2020',month='3');
...
```

Or else you can create a new table with same structure but partitioned by new partition. And then insert from old table to new table and then drop the new table.